# What is the mainline Protestant understanding of "unceasing prayer"?

Tags: exegesis, protestantism

The Bible speaks about this concept of unceasing prayer, to give some examples that seem to talk about thus:
`1 Thessalonians 5:16-18` (Rejoice always, pray without ceasing, in everything give thanks; for this is the will of God in Christ Jesus for you.),

Other verses: `Mark 13:32-37; Matthew 26:40-41;`

I've heard Eastern-Orthodox priests as having  literal interpretation of this idea. Saying that we should follow the example of hermits, retreat in the wild and pray unceasingly.

I find that to be a bit extreme and wondered how do Lutherans, Reformed, Anglican and other mainline Protestants interpret these verses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that differences of opinion might extend all the way to the individual level, rather than being settled upon by any particular denomination.

(So: what do you think it means?)

Inasmuch as I've grown up in the larger protestant tradition, I suppose my opinion might be worth more than nothing, so here goes: it sounds like an attitude to me; the continual practice of keeping short accounts with God, just another angle on loving God and loving your neighbor, just as Philippians 2 is an angle on the same.

I could be wrong, and I'm not a professional, so...

Comment: To my understanding Baptist is not a Protestant branch certainly SBC is not mainline. Some would say Baptist came from the Anabaptist movement not the Protestant movement. I suppose the questioner would still appreciate a Baptist view point though I’d be curious to know what kind of Baptist you are. The Catholic Protestant dichotomy does not envelop all denominations.

Comment: Perhaps not strictly mainline.  But to help out, since I was speaking from a generally protestant background 
I'll edit out the particular denomination.  As for me, I'm perhaps not a particularly "good" Baptist, having done time in Reformed, Methodist, Plymouth Brethren, and Community churches.

Comment: @MrConstantin Baptist is most definitely a Protestant branch! Why would you think otherwise? You are right though that Southern Baptists are not mainline.

Comment: There are a few kinds of Baptist, Old German Baptist for instance is not Protestant, they trace back to Anabaptist. There is this perception that someone is either Catholic or Protestant and the Catholic Church is making an effort to bring the Protestants back under the fold of Catholicism. Unfortunately people fail to realize that some denominations were never Catholic and did not branch out from Protestant (former Catholics). Orthodox is a major one, Anabaptist another. I did ask if he could say which kind of Baptist he was for that reason

Comment: @MrConstantin I don't know where you're getting your definitions, but the anabaptists are almost always considered Protestant, arising shortly after Luther and Zwingli and developing further from then. Modern Baptists always are. There's no conspiracy to bring everyone back to Catholicism.

Comment: Let’s just agree to disagree on this one. The Protestants claim the Anabaptist are an offshoot of the Protestant movement but the Anabaptist deny this to be true. Not to mention they were heavily persecuted by the imperial Protestant and by the Catholic Church. You may be right but the documentation is insufficient to conclude they branched out from the reformation. Especially since they come in the scene of history right at the beginning of the reformation. If it were toward the first quarter I’d say there is some case to be made possibly. Their inception may have started prior underground

Comment: Now as far as Catholics trying to bring Protestants back to the Universal Church, call it a conspiracy if you like. But it is odd some of the things the Catholic Church has officially said. Especially in view of ecumenical efforts and even changing the Catholic Church interpretation to conform with Luther’s first point in the 95 point theses and openly calling for unification with the Catholic Church now that one objection of 95 has been agreed upon.  https://youtu.be/fTMYMlEoQ7c